# How can I remove single html tags from multiple webpages

Tags: xml, web-applications, html

How can I remove single, same, HTML tag from many HTML pages? Let say I have 10000 HTML pages all with this same tag `<p> hi </p>` present in it, I want to remove this  `<p> hi </p>` tag from all of the 10000 pages.

How can I do that?

Is there any tool or web application or script that can help?

How can I do the opposite, that means if I want to, instead of removing HTML tags how can I add HTML tags to multiple websites?

Note : I want to remove the specific paragraph tags from all of my 10000 webpages I.e `<p> hi </p>` . That means my webpages may contain certain other paragraph tags like `<p> something </p>` or `<p> something </p>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you start facing these problems, it means its time for you for start using a scripting language or framework such as PHP.

These allow you to place content which you are using in multiple pages in a separate file such as **header.php** and when you want to show these in a page, you can add it using a statement such as **include "header.php"**. Therefore you can make changes to 1000 files at once by just editing one file.

However, if you still want to continue with this model of development, you can use a tool such as **Visual Studio Community** or similar. These allow you to open multiple files then search and replace in all the open documents as shown below:

[image: Visual Studio Search And Replace]

However, I still recommend you to change your development model. Using search and replace is not reliable and will break your code in most cases. A lot of free frameworks, tools and languages have been developed to avoid such situations

Answer (score 0):

I think you can remove a single tag from all file in single attempt while using Visual studio (Any version which you have) and select the tag you want to remove and replace it in the current project. I am sharing my screenshot. Have a look.
[image contain the solution of question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hMsLG.png)